# Is there a way to sync a WebCal to "My Calendars" in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-now

Currently I subscribe to a few WebCal links that a sports league I play in provides, so if my games get rescheduled, my calendar will always be up to date.

I would like to receive notifications for these events in Google Now, though. My research shows that Google Now only reads from the "My Calendars" section in Google Calendar, and any WebCal link you subscribe to will show up in the "Other Calendars" section.

Is there a way to have a WebCal show up in the "My Calendars" section? If not, is there a utility that can possibly sync the individual events from a WebCal into my own calendar so that Google Now can read them?

Comment: I'm in exactly the same position. Google Now seems to be very limited in terms of identifying which calendars and events should be shown?

Comment: As I understand it, Google Now will only read from calendars in the "My Calendars" section if you look at your calendar list on Google Calendar's webpage.

It makes sense since any feeds you subscribe to, you shouldn't be able to edit the events, so they get put into a different section. But why Google Now can't read from those calendars seems limiting.